# How can i doing for filtering for two fields in database in django and MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-views

My problem is that I want filtering for two fields ('Visible', 'user') into my database for looking in my html page the results.

I have a database (bd_mission), and have fields, and i want filtering for `Visible=True` and `user=request.user.username`, and only can with one field.

My code is:

```
def misiones(request):
    mission = bd_mission.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    return render_to_response('misiones.html',{'mission_template': mission},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I want something how:

```
mission = bd_mission.objects.filter((Visible=True)&(user=request.user.username))
```

Thanks! sorry for my bad english ! ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass multiple arguments to the `filter()` method:

```
mission = bd_mission.objects.filter(Visible=True, user=request.user.username)
```

As a side note: `filter()`/`exclude()` methods can be chained in any combinations so the code above can be written as:

```
bd_mission.objects.filter(Visible=True).filter(user=request.user.username)
```

Result in both cases will be the same.

If you want `OR` logic (`Visible=True` or `user=username`) then you can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: A valid alternative is `mission = bd_mission.objects.filter(user=request.user.username).filter(Visible=True)`. When no `JOIN`s are expected in the output query, these are identical.

Comment: You might want to mention there are slight differences between the two when used in a FK and RFK context.

Comment: Easy.. -.-' xD Thanks !

Comment: @dmg I don't think that here is the valid time to confuse Pedro with much details. Imho backward relations and annotations are pretty complex themes for newbies.